# Notepad++ or netbeans plugin for marking text in html

Tags: html, text, netbeans, notepad++

I need a plugin, which can show in another color words in HTML (and PHP) code. For example

```
<span class='domain'>this is domain</span>
```

and i need this result

> `<span class='domain'>`**this is domain**`</span>`

Is it possible?

---

And what if I have text and htm in echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Notepad++ and there Settings -> Style Configurations and from left side HTML and then modify the colors the way you like them!

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans also have a customizable html editor that can do this job.

Go

Tools>Option>Font & Color

In the syntax tab select HTML as Language and make the appropriate changes

[image]